# Count total bytes in a big file between two chars matching some rules by line

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a log file like this:

```
    2013-07-20 08:48:14-0400 [MODE LOG] Rec:'#A=1887283,FIG=18882734772,VA=772663777,T=333.4#\r\n'
    2013-07-20 08:52:34-0400 [MODE LOG] Rec:'#A=1889288,FIG=18882734772,VA=772663777,T=334.2#\r\n'
    2013-07-20 08:55:27-0400 [MODE LOG] Rec:'#A=1887283,FIG=18882732730,VA=772663777,T=335.0#\r\n'
    2013-07-20 08:58:11-0400 [MODE LOG] Rec:'#A=1887283,FIG=18882734772,VA=772663777,T=335.4#\r\n'
    2013-07-20 08:48:14-0400 [MODE LOG] Tas:'#STOPPED#\r\n'
```

With:

```
grep Rec STOM.log | grep 1887283 | grep 2013-07 | wc -c
```

I can get the bytes for the A=1887283 records from July. 
But I really need get the total bytes only from the string between ' ',
 in example: '#A=1887283,FIG=18882734772,VA=772663777,T=335.4#\r\n'
How can I do that in the best way? can I do it only with unix tools or are needed a script language? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your command to this

```
grep Rec STOM.log | grep 1887283 | grep 2013-07 | grep -oh "'.*'" | wc -c
```

**Output**

```
165
```

`'.*'` is a regular expression which will match all the characters between `'` and `'`

Answer (score 0):

extract only the data you need

```
cat file |awk -F: '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read str; do
found=''
regex="#A=(.*),F" # <#A= start string and  ,F end string>
[[ $str =~ $regex ]] && found="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo $found
done < input.txt
```

Where `input.txt` is the log file.